# Clipping Virtual Raster in QGIS 3

Tags: clip, qgis-3, virtual-layer

I have generated a virtual raster out of a large number of tifs but I am only interested in an area so I want to clip it. When I do it, it saves a raster file of several Gb. I would like to clip the virtual raster and obtain another virtual raster of the clipped area.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you simple tried to define VRT as an output format?

Comment: I have tried but it is being over 2 hours proccessing in a fast computer. Shouldn't be a quicker way?

Comment: Could you show the exact command that you use?